# How to prefix values shorter than X

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table that uses an integer for an id. I need to change this to a String and prefix all entries shorter than 4 with zeroes. The database is MySql. I converted the field to a VARCHAR(6), but not need to convert the data in the column to have it prefixed. I tried the following code, but it did not update any of the rows. Any help as to what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

```
UPDATE clients
SET clientId = 
    CASE 
    WHEN char_length(clientId) = 1 THEN '000' + clientId 
    WHEN char_length(clientId) = 2 THEN '00' + clientId
    WHEN char_length(clientId) = 3 THEN '0' + clientId
    ELSE clientId END
WHERE
    char_length(clientId) < 4;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function.

> **LPAD(str,len,padstr)**
>
> Returns the string str, left-padded with the string padstr to a length of len characters. If str is longer than len, the return value is shortened to len characters.

```
UPDATE clients
SET clientId = LPAD(clientId, 4, '0') 
WHERE
    char_length(clientId) < 4;
```

For example:

```
+------------------+
| lpad('12',4,'0') |
+------------------+
| 0012             |
+------------------+
```

Comment: Awesome, this was what I originally thought of but, found the case example and went with that. Thanks to both of you for your solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to concatenate strings: MySQL doesn't use `+` as a text concatenation operator. So the answer to "what I am doing wrong?" is "you are assuming `+` concatenates strings (texts) when it doesn't".

You need to use the [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function instead:

```
UPDATE clients
SET clientId = 
    CASE 
    WHEN char_length(clientId) = 1 THEN concat('000', clientId)
    WHEN char_length(clientId) = 2 THEN concat( '00', clientId)
    WHEN char_length(clientId) = 3 THEN concat(  '0', clientId)
    ELSE clientId 
    END
WHERE
    char_length(clientId) < 4 ;
```

You can check the different results of using `+` (or the standard `||`) in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c06e67/7/0). Notice that mySQL doesn't complain when you user `+` with strings, it just gives you an *unexpected* result. (Check what happens when you use `SELECT '1' + '2' ;` you will feel the effects of something called [coercion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercion)).

Check also [Mysql concatenation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631137/mysql-concatenation-operator) at SO.

As an alternative, @McNets answer provides a "fit for purpose" function, which is a much shorter solution.